# Why does ColorSync compression increase PDF file size for me?

Tags: pdf, conversion, compression, ebook, kindle

I have this ebook that I'm trying to send to my Kindle from my Mac. I've done this before; Get a pdf, send it to Kindle address, and make sure the subject is "convert". This causes Amazon to convert the `.pdf` to a `.azw`. Great, easy.

Now I have a pdf that's too big to attach (barely, limit is 25.0MB, and it's 36.2MB). I looked around for ways to compress it:

- Can't do zip file, Kindle won't understand.
- [Save as PDF, and use ColorSync Utility to reduce the file size (seems like the way most people do it)](https://superuser.com/a/293875/291120) like this:
  [image: Example use of ColorSync that I did]
  **And when I did this, the file size went up**

[image: WTH]

- I looked at [a way to make custom ColorSync Utilities](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15801490#15801490), and everything I tried didn't help. It seems like all the compression is doing is reducing the quality of the images *within* the pdf.
- I [even edited the XML files](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120629091437274) of some of my custom Quartz Filters in ColorSync, and still, larger file.

So I have a question that could be answered in multiple ways because all I'm trying to do is get this pdf onto my kindle in a reasonable format.

Why is this happening?

What else can I do if this won't work?

Comment: The data in many image file formats is already compressed, so there's not much that can be done except to reduce the image quality to make them smaller. An alternative might be, if it's a multipage document, to split it into individual pages.

Comment: It is a multipage document. How would I do that?

Comment: I have Acrobat Professional, which can do that. I'm sure there are free utilities available that can do the same -- just don't know what they might be, sorry.

Comment: Here's a [free online PDF splitter](http://www.splitpdf.com/).

Comment: Here's some free software called [PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/) (PDF Split and Merge) someone in a [thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3464551) on an Adobe forum recommends. There's Windows and MacOS versions of it for download from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsam/files/pdfsam/2.2.2/)

Comment: First link costs money to split the first 600 pages of my 1600+ page tome ![cost](http://i62.tinypic.com/2hx6i4l.png)

Comment: PDFsam doesn't work on macs

Comment: Don't know why ColorSync makes it bigger. There _is_ a Mac version of PDFsam for download [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsam/files/pdfsam/2.2.2/). The file is named `pdfsam-2.2.2.dmg`.

Comment: [calibre](http://www.calibre-ebook.com/) is a free and open source ebook management application that can do conversions.

Comment: You can convert the pdf with calibre and copy it to your Kindle via USB. However, the calibre pdf to mobi conversion is not as good as the one Amazon uses to my experience. It depends on your pdf if it will look good or not.

Answer (score 0):

As an above commenter mentioned, professionally published eBook PDFs, and the images they contain, are usually about as optimized as they can be. I don't know what ColorSync is, or does, but it seems like you're using it to solve the wrong problem in this particular case. Rather than fussing with the images at all, split the document up.

Adobe Acrobat retails for a little over $100 USD, and is overkill. I know on previous versions of OSX you could "Print to PDF" ([kb article](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3851)), but I'm afraid don't know if you can select what pages to print with this option, as I haven't had access to OSX in several years.

Comment: You can still "Print to PDF" is OS X 10.9.1 (Mavericks), however -- and not surprisingly -- you can't do that from the free Acrobat/Adobe Reader, and there doesn't seem to be any way to extract or save a subset of the file you are viewing. Some other view might be able to do this, but again, the quality of it's output is an unknown.